# Image under a translation -> preimage

Tags: geometry

I have the following problem in *coordinate geometry*. Note that Z simply refers to a point.

> The image of $Z(3,-8)$ under a translation is $Z'(2,2)$. What is the preimage of Z?

I have no idea how to even approach it... here's how I tried to interpret it:

1. Z'(2,2) is what happens when we perform a translation on Z(3,-8)
2. The preimage of Z is then...
3. *headdesk, I ran out of variables!*

I must just not be sleeping enough or something. What am I missing in this question? And how do I solve it?

Comment: Well, translations are bijective, so you can just look at the image under the inverse map.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon ...what?

Comment: You're likely to get more and better answers if you tell us what the notations $Z(3,-8)$, $Z'(2,2)$, and $Z$ are supposed to mean.  The last might well be the set of integers, usually denoted by $\mathbb Z$, but the first two are mysterious.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Okay, I clarified the question. They are coordinates of a point and the point after it is transformed.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon See above, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation clearly involves $$x\mapsto x-1, \quad y\mapsto y+10$$
You can easily invert this to work out what point gets mapped to $(3,-8)$.

Comment: so the answer would be $(4,-18)$?

Comment: It sure would! Yep.